# How to fix: java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

### Minimal Reproducible Example

#### Server.java

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345, 3);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // incoming request
        new WorkerThread(socket).start();
    }
}

class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;

    public WorkerThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // line 28

            // handle the request using oos and ois
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Client.java

```java
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 12345)) {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            
            // ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // line 11

            // send some data only using oos
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Thrown Exception

```java
java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2908)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2924)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3421)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:959)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397)
        at WorkerThread.run(Server.java:28)
```

---

The `WorkerThread` seems to be causing the issue, since the `SocketException` is **not** thrown if the code in the code of the `WorkerThread#run` method is placed in the `Server#main` method. See **Note** below.

The intent here is to have a separate Thread (other than the main Thread of the Server) handle each request as it comes, therefore the `WorkerThread` receives a reference to the `Socket` associated with the incoming connection.

The `WorkerThread` needs to open both `oos` and `ois` (even though they might not be both strictly needed for communication) because opening only the `ois` won't work. [Further reading on why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217245/socket-objectoutpustream-objectinputstream).

What is the underlying cause of this issue? Is there a way to fix the problem other than the hacky (?) solution presented below?

---

### Note

Running the above Client with this Server does **not** throw the Exception:

#### NonThreadedServer.java

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class NonThreadedServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345, 3);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // incoming request

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            // handle the request using oos and ois
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Uncomment line 11 of `Client`, i.e. create an `ObjectInputStream`, even though it is not strictly needed for the communication:

#### Client.java

```java
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 12345)) {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.flush();
            
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // line 11

            // send some data only using oos
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the question, I don't know what the underlying issue is or whether this solution is the correct one. If it isn't, I'll make sure to mark another answer as the accepted one.