# ObjectInputStream fails in Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, objectinputstream

I'm unable to get input and output streams from socket, my code blocks everytime it reach the getInputStream/getOutputStream.

```
class Connection implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName());
    Socket connection = null;
    Boolean serverIsDown = false;
    Thread thread = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    Context ctx = null;

    public Connection(Socket accept, Boolean serverIsDown) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connected" + accept.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        this.connection = accept;
        this.serverIsDown = serverIsDown;

        this.thread = new Thread(this, "Client Connection");
        this.thread.start();

    }

    public void init() throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Hit enter to send object");
            System.in.read();
            Request request = new Request();
            oos.writeObject(request);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(this.connection.getInputStream()); //Blocks here
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(this.connection.getOutputStream());
            this.init();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

There's no output errors when it blocks.

Comment: Always flush() the ObjectOutputStream before creating an ObjectInputStream.  This is because the format has a header the ObjectInputStream reads in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the documentation mentioned :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream(java.io.InputStream)

Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the specified InputStream. **A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified.** This constructor **will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header**.

I suggest you use two threads handling input and output stream from accepted socket,to avoid blocking. and the other better way is to use thread pool and some async io (ex;selector) instead of assigning each accepted socket with a thread.

also refer to the other post as below:
[new ObjectInputStream() blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110986/new-objectinputstream-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

You create a new stream for each object. Only create one output and one input stream. Object streams send header data which is maybe corrupted when you create a new stream.